# Create a preview page before submitting it to server MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new at .Net MVC and I'm trying to create a preview page on a click button, the preview is to present a page in a new window instead of submitting it. If the page is ok, then submitting it.
Lets say that I have this in the Html

`<input class="btnText" id="PreviewURL" value="Preview" type="submit"/>`

and in JQuery this

`$('#PreviewURL').click(function () {$('.IsPreview').val(true);submitForm();window.open(this.href);});`

But is not putting the variable IsPreview=true (I need this to use this variable in the controllers part) and what is returning isn't opening in a new window.

Comment: What is HTML for IsPreview?

Answer (score 2):

collect all the elements and value and make it them readonly, then show them in a dialog box :)

```
<div id='infor'> <span>enter name:</span> 
    <input id="nametext" type="text" />
</div>
<div id='previewDiv'>&nbsp;</div>
<a href='#' id='opendialog'>click here to preview</a>
```

jquery

```
$("#opendialog").click(function () {

     var clonetext = $('#infor').clone(true);
     $('#previewDiv').html(clonetext);
     $('#previewDiv input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     $("#previewDiv").dialog("open");
     return false;
 });
 $("#previewDiv").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     open: function () {},
     show: "blind",
     hide: "explode"
 });
```

some thing like this demo : [Preview the Page](http://jsfiddle.net/pADh2/)

Comment: I have a lot of information to preview, from forms I think, and I have to show the result in a new window, I tried what you said, but only appeared on top of the parent page

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this to work referencing a huge div around all my 20 inputs. It showed all of them and the contents in the preview dialog. woo hoo. I had the hardest time and trying to contactenate each individual input div and contents. Really interesting this .clone(true). Especially the "true" . . .it copies all the html of the div referenced.

Answer (score 1):

For best user experience , i suggest not to open preview in new window instead open a jQuery Modal Dialog. Add submit & cancel buttons in Dialog. This will be simple and fast.

But if still you want to open new window then flow will be like:

1. Create a ajax post request and post all contents to one controller (Say preview). here hold values in session. return any flag in response.
2. Upon success of request 1, open new page (say Preview) which will show all values from session. This page UI will have all posted values & a Submit button.
3. Upon click of submit, its actually going to post values.

You can use the Same controller for both POST requests, your flag IsPreview will be in header for AJAX request and will not be available for Preview page. This solution seems time taking.